# how to checkout maven mutlitmodule projects from eclipse juno

Tags: svn, maven, subclipse, eclipse-juno, multi-module

I've been trying to get a straight answer to this if possible. I'm currently using Eclipse Juno / Subclipse / Sonaytype m2eclipse. What can (if at all) I do to checkout a multi-module project from SVN such that the project appears as a single project in Eclipse? I noticed that the option to "Support multiple Maven Modules mapped to a single Eclipse workspace project" is no longer available in the Window->Preferences->Maven options list. Right now when I check-out a project I see the modules as multiple projects. Or is there something post-checkout that I should be doing to unify these under a single project view.

Thanks for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not come across that option in juno/m2e/subclipse support.

If it is massive multi module I take a checkout externally. Import only the projects to be edited/debugged.

If it is a simple multi-module I subclipse' "Checkout As" option.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. That option exists in the older versions I believe. I know I had it when I used Galileo (3.5) and m2eclipse 0.10.

Comment: Figured it out I think. I checked out the code from SVN using the Checkout as Maven Project option. Then, deleted all my workspace projects (do not delete from disk). Finally, imported my projects back into Eclipse (choosing to import Existing Maven Project(s)). I did have the option to allow nesting of modules set in the Maven preferences in Eclipse.